# How can I put my enumerate with bold type?

Tags: enumerate, bold, type

This is my code

```
\begin{enumerate}[label=(\alph*)]
\item 
\item 
\end{enumerate}
```

I tried to use `\textbf` but didn't work.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by "`\textbf` didn't work"? ... since `\begin{enumerate}[label=\textbf{(\alph*)}]` works without problem.

Answer (score 2):

I suppose you load `enumitem`. Use

```
\begin{enumerate}[label=(\alph*), font=\bfseries] \item \item \end{enumerate}
```

Answer (score 1):

In a case where it is easily avoided, it is often best to avoid loading extra packages unnecessarily. If you do not wish to load the enumitem package, you can use:

```
\begin{enumerate}
\def\theenumi{\textbf{\alph{enumi}}}
\item Bleep
\item Bloop
\end{enumerate}
```

(Note that if you have loaded the enumitem package, it will override this solution.)

If for some reason you need the parentheses to be bold as well as the letters, you can replace the \def line with

```
\renewcommand{\labelenumi}{\textbf{(\alph{enumi})}}
```